# update mysql data with replace variable

Tags: mysql

i have this text:

```
<p>[img ret872154ftu] fileaddress [/img ret872154ftu]</p>
<p>[img fd68721cvn] fileaddress [/img fd68721cvn]</p>
<p>[img xdfh654t] fileaddress [/img xdfh654t]</p>
```

i like change to this

```
<p>[img] fileaddress [/img]</p>
<p>[img] fileaddress [/img]</p>
<p>[img] fileaddress [/img]</p>
```

this code is tested but not worked

```
 UPDATE `table` SET `name` = replace(`name`, '[img (anything)', '[/img]');
```

please help

Comment: look at this similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql

Answer (score 2):

If you always have a space before and after the fileaddress, this will extract the fileaddress part:

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, '] ', -1),
  ' [', 1);
```

and you can then use this update query:

```
UPDATE `table`
SET `name` = CONCAT(
               '<p>[img] ',
               SUBSTRING_INDEX(
                 SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, '] ', -1),
                 ' [', 1),
               ' [/img]</p>');
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c0f43/1).

**Edit:** unfortunately, MySQL support for regular expressions is very limited. You could try with this quick and dirty solution, there are multiple circumstances in which it could fail, but it might work:

```
UPDATE tablename
SET
  name = 
  CONCAT(
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, '[img', 1),
    '[img]',
   SUBSTRING_INDEX(
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, '[img', -1),
      '[/img',
      1),
    ']',
    -1),
    '[/img]',
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, ']', -1)
  )
```

Fiddle is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/25b0d/1).

Comment: The big problem

this Field name is post_content on wp_posts for Wordpress
and not only previous code
test test test[img xdfh654t]http://fb.com/images/63636383481679564011.jpg[/img xdfh654t] test test test
please help me